# Powershell Start-Process permission denied

Tags: powershell, start-process

Could anyone tell me, why do I get an Error if I invoke:

```
$log = $env:TEMP + "\File.log"
$stdErrLog = $env:TEMP + "\stderr.log"
$stdOutLog = $env:TEMP + "\stdout.log"
$argument = "Get-Childitem c:\"
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials -WindowStyle hidden -WorkingDirectory c:\ -ArgumentList $argument -RedirectStandardOutput $stdOutLog -RedirectStandardError $stdErrLog -wait
```

but there is no Error if I invoke:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials -WindowStyle hidden -WorkingDirectory c:\ -ArgumentList $argument -RedirectStandardOutput $stdOutLog -RedirectStandardError $stdErrLog
```

But I need the "-wait" or is there any alternative?

Error:

```
Start-Process : Permission denied
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred -WorkingDirectory c:\ -ArgumentLi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-Process], Win32Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: What error do you get? Edit the question to include it.

Comment: Okay, error is in the Text now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your current user doesn't have access to see processes running as the 2nd account.  Launch a PowerShell window under the other account, then run the script below as yourself to see if it's visible.  If not, you may need to elevate permissions or run as admin.

```
Get-Process ([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName) | Select -ExpandProperty startinfo | Select -ExpandProperty environmentvariables | ?{$_.Name -Eq 'UserName'}
```

Comment: Oh now I understand it....my problem is my mainuser has no access to my adminuser to wait for that session...damn how can I do that now....

Comment: Can you launch powershell as admin, then run the script from there?